Error while loading conda entry point: conda-libmamba-solver (module 'libmambapy' has no attribute 'QueryFormat')
I was trying to install a conda env by running an executable file that included this command conda install mamba -n base -c conda-forge and since then i keep getting this error Error while loading conda entry point: conda-libmamba-solver (module 'libmambapy' has no attribute 'QueryFormat') every time I use conda command. I didn't notice this error affecting the functionality of conda but its frustrating.
CONDA INFO
 active environment : base
    active env location : /home/miniconda3/miniconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/evdotheo/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/evdotheo/.condarc
          conda version : 24.9.2
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.12.7.final.0
                 solver : classic
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=skylake
                          __conda=24.9.2=0
                          __cuda=12.2=0
                          __glibc=2.35=0
                          __linux=6.8.0=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /home/miniconda3/miniconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/miniconda3/miniconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
          package cache : /home/miniconda3/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /home/evdotheo/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/miniconda3/miniconda3/envs
                          /home/evdotheo/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/24.9.2 requests/2.32.3 CPython/3.12.7 Linux/6.8.0-40-generic ubuntu/22.04.4 glibc/2.35 aau/0.4.4 c/. s/. e/.
                UID:GID : 1005:1006
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

CONDA CONFIG
channels:
- conda-forge
solver: classic


Did you manage to understand why this happens?
